# jacocoTest exclusion has no effect

Tags: gradle, jacoco, test-coverage, ratpack

I have a gradle project and I want to exclude some directories from TC coverage. This is what I am giving in the task

```
jacocoTestReport {
reports {
    xml.enabled true
    csv.enabled false
    html.enabled true
}

afterEvaluate {
    classDirectories.setFrom(files(classDirectories.files.collect {
        fileTree(dir: it).exclude(
            // define here
            'com/this/that'
        )
    }))
}

}
```

However the classes still shows up in the coverage.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

`afterEvaluate` runs in Gradle's configuration phase which is before any tasks have executed and before any classes have been compiled (see [build phases](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:build_phases))

I'm guessing you want something like

```
test {
   jacoco {
      excludes = ['com/this/that/*'] 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Hi. I tried this but this is not working. The directory is still getting included

Comment: Did you try `excludes = ['com/this/that/**/*.class']`

Comment: Yes, Tried this too. this is indeed very weird